# Button is not getting the ViewState Value and no error message shown

Tags: c#, asp.net

i have been trying to use the ViewState object to store the counter for clicking the ImageButton.For instance if ImageButton1 is click it will store the counter == 1(or increment) in it if another button is clicked the counter will become null.I tried clicking the imagebutton , the counter becomes 1 however when i try to retrieve from the submit button via the if else statement it retrieves nothing and the button cannot work.In addition no error message has been shown.I am developing something like a seat selector for my project.Any help will be greatly appreciated!.Below are the codes

```
protected void ImageButton1_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
    {


        if (ImageButton1.ImageUrl != "~/Images/bed-occupied.png")
        {
            ImageButton1.ImageUrl = "~/Images/bed-occupied.png";

            if (ViewState["Counter"] == null)
            {
                counterBed1 = 1;
                TextBoxClass.Text = counterBed1.ToString();
            }
            else
            {
                counterBed1 = (int)ViewState["Counter"] + 1;
            }

             }
        else
        {
            ImageButton1.ImageUrl = "~/Images/bed-unoccupied.png";
            ViewState["Counter"] = null;

        }

    }


 protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ViewState["Counter"] = counterBed1;
       // if(ViewState["Counter"] != null)
        if(counterBed1 ==1)
        {



            Panel_ErrorMsg.Visible = true;
            lb_ErrorMsg.Text = "Patient Successfully admitted to hospital";

        }




        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are incrementing the value as well as setting a local variable but please note you are never storing the value back in `ViewState` object.

```
int counterBed1 = 0;
if (ImageButton1.ImageUrl != "~/Images/bed-occupied.png")
 {
      ImageButton1.ImageUrl = "~/Images/bed-occupied.png";
      if (ViewState["Counter"] == null)
      {
          counterBed1 = 1;
          TextBoxClass.Text = counterBed1.ToString();
          ViewState["Counter"] = counterBed1; // Add This
       }
       else
       {
           counterBed1 = (int)ViewState["Counter"] + 1;
           ViewState["Counter"] = counterBed1; //Add This
       }
  }
  else
  {
      ImageButton1.ImageUrl = "~/Images/bed-unoccupied.png";
      ViewState["Counter"] = null;
  }
```

Also, don't use class variable as it will be re-initialized after every new request, use local variable instead like this in Submit Button handler:-

```
protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     int counterBed1 = Convert.ToInt32(ViewState["Counter"]);
     // if(ViewState["Counter"] != null)
     if(counterBed1 ==1)
     {
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the all the help it works now , however may i ask what do you mean by never storing the value back in the viewState object?.As i tried clicking other ImageButtons before clicking imageButton1 back. The counter is reset to 0 and could not increment again.

Comment: @GX-X - That's because you are storing the values in global variable(defined at class level), Please use local variables as suggested in `Submit` button click handler. _What I mean by storing back_ is that you have the value but you need to store that value in `ViewState` object to fetch it back in second round trip. I would strongly suggest you to read about programming and more about web rather than writing the code directly.

Comment: I see , thanks alot of the kind advice. Indeed i had learn something new here.